# Count the number of occurrences of a name in the same row as an item that matches an item in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

The example below is a truncated example of my spread sheet.

What I'd like is a count of the number of times each person (`Name1` - `Name4`) is listed in the `Out Of Hours` row on a date that is a Bank Holiday.

So in this shortened example, I'd be looking for the following counts -

- Name1: 0
- Name2: 1
- Name3: 0
- Name4: 0

I have investigated the use of `COUNTIF`, `COUNTIFS`, `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` but I don't believe they can help. However, I'm hoping there is a combination of those functions that can be used to get the required count.

|  | Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 01/01/2023 | 02/01/2023 | 03/01/2023 | 04/01/2023 | 05/01/2023 | 06/01/2023 |
| Name1 |  | Out | Out | Out | Out | Out |
| Name2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Name3 |  |  |  |  | Out | Out |
| Name4 |  | Out | Out | Out | Out | Out |
| Out Of Hours | Name2 | Name2 | Name2 | Name2 | Name2 | Name2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bank Holidays |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02/01/2023 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Seems like `COUNTIF(s)` fit the bill.  Please advise what you have tried and why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but If I knew why it failed I wouldn't need to seek assistance.

Comment: You are a new user and I see how you might have misinterpreted my comment.  My comment was not intended to offend you, it is a fundamental part of how this site works.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)  *"Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!*  Hope you stick around and enjoy it as much as I do.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT function.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "*I don't believe they can help.*" ?

To get the counts of `Name2` in row 8 : `=COUNTIF($B$8:$G$8,"Name2")` which will return 6 in your example.

Replace the `$B$8:$G$` with the correct range where you want to count the names.

You can create a table with all the names you want to check, and rewrite the above as `=COUNTIF($B$8:$G$8,A4)`, (because your "Name1" is in `A4`) then drag it down to replace `A4` by `A5`,A6`... to count all the names:

[image]

If you have many rows with '*Out Of Hours*', you can try this formula:

```
=SUM(IF(IF(A3:A14="Out Of Hours",B3:G14)="Name2",1,0))
```

- inner if: check column A for rows (3 to 14) with "Out of Hours, if true, return the rows in column B to G, otherwise 0
- then check the rows above for "Name 2", if true return 1
- then sum the above

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try this, but it's not quite what I'm looking for I have added an answer that shows how I finally managed to achieve my desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

While `COUNTIFS()` was used, `SUPPRODUCT()` was the missing piece.

- `$B$2:$G$2` represents the dates.
- `$A10:$A18` represents the bank holiday dates (only `A10` is shown on the example).
- `$B$7:$G$7` represents the person working 'Out of hours'
- `$A3` represents 'Name1'

This formula will be copied to four cells, one representing each name.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($B$2:$G$2, $A10:$A18, $B$7:$G$7, $A3)))
```

The additional cells now show the desired count.

```
| Name1 | 0 |
| Name2 | 1 |
| Name3 | 0 |
| Name4 | 0 |
```

Comment: I suggested an edit that removes unnecessary informationfrom an otherwise good answer.  Look forward to seeing you around [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)